# Interceptor error in Controller magento2

Tags: magento2, error, catalog, interceptor

**Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index" />
```

**Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Result;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $catalogSession,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    Http $request,
    LayoutInterface $layout,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,

    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $catalogCategoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Client\Connector $tglssearchClientConnector
) {
    $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->layout = $layout;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->catalogCategoryFactory = $catalogCategoryFactory;
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->tglssearchClientConnector = $tglssearchClientConnector;

    /* $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
     $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
     $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;
     $this->_storeManager = $storeManager; */
    parent::__construct(
        $context
    );
}
public function execute()
{
   ....

   $rootCategory = $this->catalogCategoryFactory->create()
        ->load($rootCategoryId)
        ->setName($this->__('Sale'))   //ERROR HERE
        ->setMetaTitle($this->__('Sale'))
        ->setMetaDescription($this->__('Sale'))
        ->setMetaKeywords($this->__('Sale'));
     ....
```

In the line `->setName($this->__('Sale'))`

Why do i get **Interceptor error**...What does this mean?

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor::__() in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_3\app\code\Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index.php on line 143
```

Comment: Did you try to empty `/var/generation/`? It might be an issue like this one: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101456/magento-2-object-manager-is-passing-another-object-then-expected-why

Comment: yes cleared var/gen and ran setup upgrade

Comment: Any idea where s the root cause?

Comment: Can you add the rest of the controller and the module structure? And is this the actual error, or did you change to post it here? `Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor::__()`? Is it actually looking in `Vendor\Module\Controller`?

Comment: Updated my controller @Akif, no i haven't edited the error..it is as is i got

Comment: Can you find out which part of the line causes the error? `->setName` or `$this->__()`?

Comment: $this->() was causing the error i just gave ->setName('Sale'). Thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The translation function `__()` is defined in `app/functions.php` and is not a part of `$this`. You should call it directly, without `$this`, as follows:

```
public function execute()
{
   ....

   $rootCategory = $this->catalogCategoryFactory->create()
      ->load($rootCategoryId)
      ->setName(__('Sale'))   //no more error
      ->setMetaTitle(__('Sale'))
      ->setMetaDescription(__('Sale'))
      ->setMetaKeywords(__('Sale'));
       ....
}
```

Comment: Yes @Peedee, thanks for the explanation...:)